# How change the mapping type from "_doc" to "doc"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of data indexed in multiple indexes using the '_doc' mapping type. I need to change the mapping type to 'doc'. I think *_update_by_query* or *reindex* API might help me but I was unable to find the appropriate query for it.

Is it possible to change the mapping type? What is the easiest way to do it?

I use version 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion is better to reindex the data with appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use reindex API?

Comment: You need to write a script to take documents from old and insert in the new index. One approach is to use scan and scroll API for large documents. For smaller set, we can achieve using Re-Index API and I provide with you the link.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html
If it works give me some boost by ranking my answer. It would be appreciated.